# Experience of Time by observers in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, relativity, time-dilation

I want to know how to obtain the "experience of time" of an observer moving on an arbitary timelike worldline. By "experience of time" I mean the time expereinced by the observer as a function on coordinate time, at any point on it's world line. Literature says that it is the "proper time" of that path. But the mathematical definition of "proper time" just makes it a paramatrization of the path that is affinely connected to the arc length. Now in GR, time and space are in the same footing (in a sense). So, why should "proper time" or arc length be interpreted as giving the experience of time of the observer? It might as well give a measure of space or maybe an "unphysical" mixture of time and space.

Answer (score 1):

Our observer is moving on an arbitary *timelike* worldline, so the tangent at any point on that worldline is also timelike. Thus that tangent is the worldline of a comoving frame of constant velocity (and of course the tangent is purely timelike in that comoving frame) and our observer's clock ticks at the same rate as the clock in the comoving frame. So the proper time of our observer is essentially the sum of the proper times of all those tangential comoving frames.

Answer (score 0):

Time $t$ in classical physics - which is a parameter - and used to parameterize the path in Euclidean space, has been promoted to a coordinate in space-time. Hence time and space are on the same footing - as you pointed out. It's replacement is the proper time - typically denoted as $\tau$ - which is now the parameter for the path in space-time. You still experience time in your rest frame as you would in a rest frame in classic physics. It's how you measure time in a frame moving relative to your rest frame which has changed. In short, relativity is about how you make time and space measurements when time and space are coupled.